# Is there any python IDE for Windows that has something like visual studio's auto-fill or object browser?

Tags: windows, python, ide

I've been working hard on C# and I've been using Visual Studio whole time!
And it is about 1 year that I started Python.
And I have a big problem with Python: There's no object browser or auto-fill.
Visual Studio offers a great auto-fill and an object browser so you can see what variables and functions are defined under the class/library.
Is there any Python IDE for Windows that at least offers an object browser to see all library elements?
It would be good if I don't pay money for that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python Tools for Visual Studio plug in offers "syntax highlighting, debugging and rich intellisense, unit testing, refactoring, **object browser**, MPI cluster debugging, Django intellisense and debugging, development REPL window and a debugging REPL window".

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/python/

For a list of other IDEs and their functionalities:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments